# Simplify CSS code

Tags: css

How can i simplify this code?

```
#user_panel .subscribe, 
#user_panel .faves, 
#user_panel .tags,
#user_panel .title,
#user_panel .calendar a,
#user_panel .item .content
{
    color:#fc0;
}
```

I don`t want to write #user_panel all time. Any ways?

Comment: Use a name that's shorter like #up ?

Answer (score 6):

How about [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (less CSS)? Makes your life so much easier!

```
#user_panel {
   .subscribe, .faves, .tags, .title, .calendar a, .item .content {
      color:#fc0;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Accoding to a comment, LESS is only useful if you use Ruby. This is totally wrong. LESS is **written in Ruby** (do not confuse with **only compatible with**) and comes with a command-line tool `less2css` to convert your `*.less` files to `*.css` files.

Comment: +1 for the link, hadn't heard of that before but have wanted to write something similar for ages.

Comment: There is also something called SASS http://sass-lang.com/ (inspired the creators of LESS). Python/Ruby/YAML developers love it, but I deem LESS easier to learn if you come from CSS - it's an evolution instead of a revolution.

Comment: @graphicdevine: I would not say that it's only useful if you use Ruby. There are LESS-plugins for .NET already. At its core it is just a command-line tool (which is written in Ruby) and can be used for any purpose (even static websites).

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go with the most common answer, since you haven't given me a reason not to :-)

```
#user_panel
{
   color:#fc0;
}
```

The other alternative is to add an extra class on every element, and then reference multiple classes when you need it, e.g:

```
.highlight 
{
  color:#fc0;
}

<div id="user_panel">
  <span class="subscribe highlight"></span>  
  <span class="tags highlight"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe only if the item has certain classes this style needs to be applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can give each of those elements a second class called .user-panel-control and change the CSS to this:

```
#user_panel .user-panel-control
{ 
    color:#fc0; 
}
```

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="user_panel">
  <span class='subscribe user-panel-control'>This is a user panel control</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats about as short as you're going to get. You could rename user_panel but you should try to keep your identifiers descriptive to make maintaining your code easier. The obvious question is, do your selectors even require the #user_panel portion?

Potentially you could do:

```
#user_panel *{ color: #fc0 }
```

or do as Jon has below.