# Simplifying CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some CSS properties to be applied to a lot of ids.I need to simplify my code as there are about 20 ids!
Here is my CSS:

```
 #a1_build ul,#a2_build ul,#a1_build li,#a2_build li,
 #a1_apply ul,#a2_apply ul,#a1_apply li,#a2_apply li,
 #a1_learn ul,#a2_learn ul,#a1_learn li,#a2_learn li
 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }
#a1_build ,#a2_build,
#a1_apply ,#a2_apply,
#a1_learn ,#a2_learn
       {
         margin-top:1em;
       }

#a1_build li,#a2_build li,#a1_apply li,#a2_apply li,
#a1_learn li,#a2_learn li
 { 
    width:696px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    }
```

Now, the ids are going to be a1_build, a2_build....a10_build, a1_apply, a2_apply......a10_apply and a1_learn, a2_learn.....a10_learn.
I want to be able to generalize it as 'a'+n+'_build', 'a'+n+'_apply' and 'a'+n+'_learn' and make n go from 1-10 which will make it a whole lot easier! How can i do this?

Comment: You can't do that with 'normal' CSS. Can't you assign a class to every element?

Comment: why not to use `class`es rather that `id`s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplify CSS code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266249/simplify-css-code)

Comment: oh yes that would be way easier! thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it, using the match end of string selector `[a$=b]` which the end of a particular attribute. This works in IE7 and above.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/BMdvd/)

```
[id$=build] ul,
[id$=apply] ul,
[id$=learn] ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
[id$=build],
[id$=apply],
[id$=learn] {
    margin-top:1em;
}

[id$=build] li,
[id$=apply] li,
[id$=learn] li { 
    width:696px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

### Alternative method

I recommend against this though and using a more class-based approach, something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/hwHpP/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="a1" class="a_section">
    <ul class="build">
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a_section .build {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ill use your alternative method!

Comment: @priyanka don't forget to accept the answer by hitting the tick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS nth-child selector..

```
p:nth-child(2) 
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Here's a great tutorial

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: This is great! I think ill use this a lot later! Thanks for the reference!